# Manipulating a summation expression for Future Value (Annuities)

Tags: sequences-and-series, economics

I've been given the following expressions for regular payments with regular annual compounding (Annuities):

(1) $$ F - (1 + r)F $$
(2) $$ F = d \sum^T _{t=1} (1+r)^{T-t}$$

where: ($F$) is a Future Value, ($r$) is the Rate of Interest, ($d$) is the payment amount, ($T$) is the total count of payments and ($t$) is the payment number.
I understand how to get to this point,

(3) $$ d\left[\sum^T_{t=1}(1+r)^{T-t} - \sum^T_{t=1}(1+r)^{T-t+1}\right] $$

but somehow my tutor has managed to manipulate the expression to,

(4) $$ -d[(1+r)^T - 1] $$

Does anyone know what my tutor did to go from (3) to (4)?

Comment: Using \Sigma instead of \sum is the reason why you saw $\displaystyle\Sigma_{t=1}^T$ instead of $\displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^T$.  (I fixed that and also attended to sizes of brackets and other things. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks Micheal, though the way I had it before was how my tutor had expressed it.

Comment: It looks much better how you have displayed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a telescoping property.  The easiest way to understand it is to pick a value for $T$, say $T = 3$, and write out the sums explicitly:

$$\sum_{t=1}^T (1+r)^{T-t} = (1+r)^2 + (1+r)^1 + (1+r)^0,$$ and $$\sum_{t=1}^T (1+r)^{T-t+1} = (1+r)^3 + (1+r)^2 + (1+r)^1.$$  So their difference is simply $$-(1+r)^3 + (1+r)^0 = -((1+r)^3 - 1),$$ because all the intermediate terms cancel.  Now generalize this for any positive integer $T$, and you can see where the result comes from.